# strange query perf result - different expression number of 'in clause' in greenplum 5.0

Tags: sql, greenplum

i notice strange result when using 'in clause' in greenplum 5.0.

when expression number of 'in clause' <= 25, query linearly slows down(as expected), but when expression number > 25, query is obviously faster (than number = 25). why does this happen?

i explain the query, run using new/legacy optimizer, output is the same. here's query sql and explain result.

**query 1 - 26 expression number**

sql:

```sql
select * from table1 
where column1 in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26')
```

query time: 0.8s ~ 0.9s

explain:

```
Gather Motion 8:1  (slice1; segments: 8)  (cost=0.00..481.59 rows=2021 width=1069)
  ->  Table Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..475.60 rows=253 width=1069)
        Filter: column1 = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}'::text[])
Settings:  optimizer=on
Optimizer status: PQO version 2.42.0
```

explain analyze:

```
Gather Motion 8:1  (slice1; segments: 8)  (cost=0.00..481.53 rows=2003 width=1064)
  Rows out:  0 rows at destination with 52 ms to end, start offset by 0.477 ms.
  ->  Table Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..475.63 rows=251 width=1064)
        Filter: column1 = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}'::text[])
        Rows out:  0 rows (seg0) with 51 ms to end, start offset by -358627 ms.
Slice statistics:
  (slice0)    Executor memory: 437K bytes.
  (slice1)    Executor memory: 259K bytes avg x 8 workers, 281K bytes max (seg7).
Statement statistics:
  Memory used: 262144K bytes
Settings:  optimizer=on
Optimizer status: PQO version 2.42.0
Total runtime: 53.107 ms
```

**query 2 - 25 expression number**

sql:

```sql
select * from table1 
where column1 in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25')
```

query time: 1.2s ~ 1.5s

explain:

```
Gather Motion 8:1  (slice1; segments: 8)  (cost=0.00..481.59 rows=2021 width=1069)
  ->  Table Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..475.60 rows=253 width=1069)
        Filter: column1 = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}'::text[])
Settings:  optimizer=on
Optimizer status: PQO version 2.42.0
```

explain anaylze:

```
Gather Motion 8:1  (slice1; segments: 8)  (cost=0.00..481.53 rows=2003 width=1064)
  Rows out:  0 rows at destination with 60 ms to end, start offset by 0.517 ms.
  ->  Table Scan on table1 (cost=0.00..475.63 rows=251 width=1064)
        Filter: column1 = ANY ('{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25}'::text[])
        Rows out:  0 rows (seg0) with 59 ms to end, start offset by -155783 ms.
Slice statistics:
  (slice0)    Executor memory: 437K bytes.
  (slice1)    Executor memory: 191K bytes avg x 8 workers, 191K bytes max (seg0).
Statement statistics:
  Memory used: 262144K bytes
Settings:  optimizer=on
Optimizer status: PQO version 2.42.0
Total runtime: 60.584 ms
```

gp runs in 3 vm, 1 master and 2 segment, each segment has 4 data directory.

table1 has 500,000 rows with 50 columns, primary key and distribute key is one another column, in uuid. column1 is not a distribute key or primary key, just one of a nature key.

Answer (score 0):

you can run explain analyze to see what exactly the plan spent time on.  Share it here.

Comment: runtimes are around 60ms. I don't think there is any difference on db level.